# Auto relacionamento no EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

Preciso fazer um auto-relacionamento em uma das entidades, como faço para referenciar a propria entidade tanto para registros filhos como para o registro pai

```
public class Comentario
{
    public int IdComentario { get; set; }
    public int? IdComentarioPai { get; set; }
    public string Texto { get; set; }
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Comentario> Respostas { get; set; }
    public Comentario ComentarioPai { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ajuste sua classe do modelo para o seguinte:

```
public class Comentario
{
    [Key]
    public int ComentarioId { get; set; }
    public int? ComentarioPaiId { get; set; }

    public string Texto { get; set; }
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }

    public virtual Comentario ComentarioPai { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Comentario> Respostas { get; set; }
}
```

Na configuração do contexto, adicione também:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Comentario>()
        .Property(c => c.ComentarioPaiId).IsOptional();
        .HasMany(c => c.Respostas).WithOptional(c => c.ComentarioPai).HasForeignKey(c => c.ComentarioId);
}
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, Obrigado.